# How to list files/directories only in fishshell?

Tags: fish

In fish:

```
for x in *
   echo $x
end
```

The `*` here includes all directories and files, how to list files(or directories) only?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

fish does not have lots of fancy globbing syntax. However, directories can be iterated like so:

```
for x in */
    echo $x
end
```

For files, or more sophisticated checks, you can use `test`:

```
for x in *
    if test -f $x
        echo $x
    end
end
```

or `find`:

```
for x in find . -type f -maxdepth 1
    echo $x
end
```